# Can't change account on Facebook login screen

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I use facebook on iOS. Why on facebook login screen I can't change login by another account?
For login I use

```
    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    }];
```

Thanks!

Comment: how you are logging in? Through safari or settings app?

Comment: I use safari for loggin.

Answer (score 0):

This is because safari will cache your login credential in cookie. Inorder to clear the cookie go to the **settings app** select safari **Clear Cookies and Data**.

[image]

Comment: You are wrong. I saw another samples from facebook. They have button login by another user and show image of application and user. In my login screen I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing cookies didn't worked. Logging out from Facebook in Safari may be necessary.